# npm installation through VSCode terminal is throwing an error

Tags: node.js, npm

While trying to install npm through VSCode terminal I am getting the below error:::

5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
**7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-saas 1177ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-saas 1027ms**
**9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for node-saas@latest 404 Not Found - GET** **https://registry.npmjs.org/node-saas - Not found**

Any Idea how to resolve this? I am using the command : "npm install node-saas -D"

Thanks and Regards
Saurabh

Comment: Did you want an NPM package named `node-saas` or `node-sass`?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the packages available on https://npmjs.org and the `node-saas` package doesn't exist. I believe the package you are looking for is `node-sass` and not the former

Running `npm install node-sass` should yield the required package